# I am trying to password lock my application, but its not workig

Tags: android, if-statement, password-protection

here is my code, I don't know what I am doing wrong. But its not working! Ideally what I want is if all the textviews are empty it should toast "please fill the details" or else "saved" but some how it always toasts "saved"

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText et1;
EditText et2;
EditText et3;
EditText et4;
EditText et5;
Button b;

FileOutputStream fos1;
FileOutputStream fos2;
FileOutputStream fos3;
FileOutputStream fos4;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    et4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    et5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    b.setOnClickListener(this); 
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String password=et1.getText().toString();
    String confirmPassword=et2.getText().toString();
    String secQues=et3.getText().toString();
    String secAns=et4.getText().toString();
    String hint=et5.getText().toString();


    if(password!=null && confirmPassword!=null && secQues!=null && secAns!=null && hint!=null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all the details.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings will always be not `null` since they're generated by the EditTexts. However, the String you get can be an empty String (`""`) of length 0. This means you should compare the length of the String instead. [TextUtils will work much better here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword)  && !TextUtils.isEmpty(secQues)   && !TextUtils.isEmpty(secAns)  && !TextUtils.isEmpty(hint)){
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also since you have a lot of `EditTexts`, a nicer way of checking is by making an array of EditTexts, then looping and checking the length. If anything empty is found, set the boolean flag to false and exit the loop.

```
boolean noneEmpty = true;

for (int x =0; x < editTextArray.length;x++)
{
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextArray[x].getText()))
  {
    noneEmpty = false;
    break;
  }
}

if(noneEmpty){
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please fill all the details.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```